# Finding position of maximum element in C, location instance

Tags: c, arrays

The maximum elements position in an array 'array[n]' has to be found, hence using the following code

```
int i, maximum; int location = 1;

//the array value and n value will be scanned in
maximum = array[0];

for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
    if(array[i] > maximum){
        maximum = array[i];
        location = i+1;
    }
}

return location;
```

this returns the output for example array below

```
(int[]) {1, 2, 3}, 3     -> location 3
(int[]) {5, 15, 4, 7}, 4 -> location 2
```

hence in the case of above array the code works well. when an array contains the two or more instance of the greater number, the code fails.

```
(int[]) {15, 15, 5, 7}, 4    -> location 1 (checks 1st location and stays)
(int[]) {45, 23, 55, 45}, 4  -> location 2 (checks 1st location and stays)
```

to solve the maximum instance location problem, how can the next instance location be found?

Comment: Do your comparison as `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: The code is not failing, your logic is.

Comment: Array indexing is from `0`. Please don't try to make it `1`. If you want to do that, adjust it at the  human interface, when you print it. `location = i; ... printf("%d",location+1);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin The comparison using ">=" works well, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in the examples you have given

```
(int[]) {1, 2, 3}, 3     -> location 3
(int[]) {5, 15, 4, 7}, 4 -> location 2
```

`3` in the first example is in the same position as `4` in the second example, so they should technically have the same location. I'm not sure which code you've used to determine these locations, but it's inconsistent.

Your third and fourth examples are similarly inconsistent. This inconsistency puts doubt on your requirements, despite the clarity of the rest of the question.

A full minimal testcase is usually required for StackOverflow. The requirements are:

- Your code must be minimal. Whatever the problem is, it should be easy for us to spot. As a guideline, if your code is greater than 50 lines you should try to trim any unnecessary logic away, filling in the gaps with static values where necessary.
- If your problem is an error message, your code must produce the same error message.
- If your problem is logical, your code must compile and run, producing the errant behaviour without us having to fill in the blanks or correct any errors, preferably without us even having to enter any input.

Your code doesn't compile, but it's easy enough to wrap it into a function and add a `main` entry point so it does. It would be best if, in the future, you were to take these steps in producing your minimal testcase.

```
size_t get_first_maximum_index(int *array, size_t array_size) {
    int i, maximum; int location = 1;

    //the array value and n value will be scanned in
    maximum = array[0];

    for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
        if(array[i] > maximum){
            maximum = array[i];
            location = i+1;
        }
    }

    return location;
}
```

I have taken the liberty to add the required interface to your code, but I've left your code unchanged. All you have to do is connect the logic to the interface:

- Use `array_size` instead of `n`.
- return actual array indexes, rather than array indexes + 1.
- Suggestion: Use `size_t` instead of `int` for array indexes (`i` and `location`), since array indexes should never be negative.

Once you've done that, you should be able to use this function to gather the initial maximum index like so: `size_t index = get_first_maximum_index(array, array_size);`

... as for each instance of the same value, you'll need a different function, which I suggest be named `get_next_maximum_index`.

```
size_t get_next_maximum_index(int *array, size_t array_size, int current_maximum) {
     /* XXX:
      * Find the next value within array that contains current_maximum and return it,
      * ... or array_size if none found
      */
}
```

I feel confident that, providing you were the one who wrote the code you posted in the OP, you should be able to finish that function off yourself. It would follow that an example of finding the first and subsequent indexes for maximum values would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "maximum_int_search.h"

int main(void) {
    int array[] = { 15, 15, 5, 7 };
    size_t array_size = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
    size_t index = get_first_maximum_index(array, array_size);
    do {
        printf("Maximum value at array[%zu]: %d\n", index, array[index]);
        index = get_next_maximum_index(array + index + 1, array_size - index - 1);
    } while (index != array_size);
}
```

If you have any problems with these tasks, feel free to ask further questions in the comments.